# C++ Win32 Menubar being drawn over owner-drawn menu items

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, drawing, ownerdrawn

I have 2 owner-drawn menu items, when I launch the program I only see one of the owner-drawn menu items; the first one. It is being drawn except the menubar is drawn over every other menu item which is not drawn in the first position, If I mouse over the second owner-drawn menu item or update it in any other way it draws, If I then interact with the main window (i.g Resizing) in effect updating the menu bar it proceeds to draw over any other owner-drawn item that is not drawn in the first position.

Question: How do I get the menubar to not drawn over menu items,

// Measure Item:

```
VOID MeasureMenuItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT ItemStruct)
{
    ItemStruct->itemWidth = 50;
    ItemStruct->itemHeight = 10;
    return;
}
```

// Draw Item:

```
VOID DrawMenuItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT ItemStruct)
{
    HDC hDC = ItemStruct->hDC;

    SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    if (ItemStruct->itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT)
    {
        SetDCPenColor(hDC, RGB(20, 20, 20));
        SetDCBrushColor(hDC, RGB(20, 20, 20));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    }
    else
    {
        SetDCPenColor(hDC, RGB(70, 70, 70));
        SetDCBrushColor(hDC, RGB(70, 70, 70));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    }
    Rectangle(hDC, ItemStruct->rcItem.left, ItemStruct->rcItem.top, ItemStruct->rcItem.right, ItemStruct->rcItem.bottom);

    DrawText(hDC, (LPCWSTR)ItemStruct->itemData, -1, &ItemStruct->rcItem, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
    ReleaseDC(MainWindow, hDC);
    return;
}
```

// Menus

```
    HMENU Bar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU File = CreateMenu();
    HMENU Edit = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenu(Bar, MF_OWNERDRAW, (UINT_PTR)File, L"File");
    AppendMenu(Bar, MF_OWNERDRAW, (UINT_PTR)Edit, L"Edit");
    MENUINFO Info;
    Info.cbSize = sizeof(Info);
    Info.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND;
    Info.hbrBack = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100, 100, 100));
    SetMenuInfo(Bar, &Info);
    SetMenu(MainWindow, Bar);
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is `DrawMenuItem()` calling `ReleaseDC(MainWindow, hDC);`? That doesn't belong there, get rid of it. You didn't obtain the `HDC` from `Get(Window)DC()` so you don't own it and shouldn't be trying to release it.

Also, you are not un-selecting the objects you selected into the `HDC`. You need to restore the original objects you replaced.

Try this instead:

```cpp
VOID DrawMenuItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT ItemStruct)
{
    HDC hDC = ItemStruct->hDC;

    HPEN oldPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);

    if (ItemStruct->itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT)
    {
        SetDCPenColor(hDC, RGB(20, 20, 20));
        SetDCBrushColor(hDC, RGB(20, 20, 20));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    }
    else
    {
        SetDCPenColor(hDC, RGB(70, 70, 70));
        SetDCBrushColor(hDC, RGB(70, 70, 70));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    }

    Rectangle(hDC, ItemStruct->rcItem.left, ItemStruct->rcItem.top, ItemStruct->rcItem.right, ItemStruct->rcItem.bottom);

    DrawText(hDC, (LPCWSTR)ItemStruct->itemData, -1, &ItemStruct->rcItem, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

    SelectObject(hDC, oldPen);
    SelectObject(hDC, oldBrush); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate! I was starting feeling down that I couldn't figure it out, The reason why I am not doing those is just out of my foolishness, my bad haha, owe you one!